# Booting Up Properly

Tags: 16.04, boot, chromeos

I am somewhat to Ubuntu. Everything seems fine when I install Ubuntu on modern laptops. But when I attempted to use a Chromebook for installing up Ubuntu, the output of the terminal gave me:

> gfxboot initialization failed
>
> > boot:

The "help" key and typing "help" doesn't work.
Is anyone familiar with this problem? I used SeaBIOS for dual-booting Chrome OS and Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you install ubuntu using  `crouton` or erased everything and then installed ?

Comment: I didn't do either of those. I tried dual booting with SeaBIOS.

Comment: Please mention that in your post to prevent confusion and receiving better response.

Comment: @ankit7540 Sorry, I tried to understand. I didn't read it clearly. I erased everything then tried to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 3 years since this post has occurred. I have found a common solution that is already wide open to the public. Simply put, typing `help` and pressing the enter key will resolve the problem. This has somehow allowed my Chromebook to boot up with the graphic interface.